# Showing MessageBox when value is lower than -

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically I want a MessageBox that appears when my Form is loaded that is saying that the value is lower than a constant value ( like 30 ).
This is the code I just wrote but its not working since the IF condition is not syntactly correct.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|DataMG.mdb";

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select COUNT(*) from Prodotti where Disponibilta < 30";

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();

        var count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (count < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Attenzione alcuni prodotti sono in disponibilita' limitata!");
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

What should I do ?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "value"? The count of records that is returned or a scalar value that is returned by your query?

Comment: I think you should use "Select Disponibilita from Prodotti where Disponibilita < 30" to retrieve directly from db, then you can use a scalar, that returns the first column of the first row.

Comment: Basically I want to check if there is even one product that has availability under 30.

Comment: `Select COUNT(*)` will never return a value < 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ExecuteNonQuery()` with a simple `SELECT` statement, `SQLDataReader` is quicker and the proper way to do this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Prodotti WHERE Disponibilta < 30";

conn.Open();

MySqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(myReader.HasRows)
{
    //This means you have at least one product with less than 30.
}

myReader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Indeed, I knew that an SQLCommand couldnt work used in that condition. I just tried it

Comment: Then try `myReader.GetInt32("Disponibilta")`

Comment: int value = myReader.GetInt32("Disponibilta"); That string isnt working , it says that some parameters are invalid

Comment: I've modified my answer to suit what you said in the comment under your question. The code will now only tell you if there exist any products with Disponibilita of less than 30.

Comment: should be the name of the column - the GetInt32 requires a column INDEX - not an named value. to get the named value do myReader.GetInt32(myReader.GetOrdinal("Disponibilita"))

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select COUNT(*) from Prodotti where Disponibilta < 30";

    var count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Attenzione alcuni prodotti sono in disponibilita' limitata!");
        //connection.Close(); wrap connection around an using
    }
}
```

Basically you ask to database the number of Prodotti that Disponibilta < 30, so if any you show the messagebox.

**EDIT**

I assume that Disponibilta is a numeric.

Comment: Disponibilta is numeric. The way you did the code isnt working, it doesnt show anything at the Load of my Form

Comment: Any exception? are you sure that you have products with Disponibilita < 30?

Comment: Yup. I put everything into a button right now so it is clearer than before, check back my first post

Comment: Ok after putting it in a button i get this exception : "No value specified for some requested parameters. " (Nessun valore specificato per alcuni parametri necessari.)

Comment: @Kiirito post your exception to give us more info.

Comment: "No value specified for some requested parameters. "

Comment: @Kiirito Ok what type of exception? what line throw the exception?

Comment: @Kiirito are you sure tha isn't `Disponibilita` and not `Disponibilta` note the `i`.

Answer (score 0):

`Select` keyword introduces a query, so you have to use `.ExecuteReader()`.`.ExecuteNonQuery()` is used for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE` and return value is the number of rows affected.

For your situation, create a reader and check the first value

```
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read() 
{ 
    if (reader[0] < aValue) //make here the appropiate conversion
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Attenzione alcuni prodotti sono in disponibilita' limitata!");
        connection.Close();
        break;//maybe return?
    }
}
```